# How to sum up all the employee salaries and update it to one attribute in the array embedded doc in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to sum up all the EMP_SALARY = (9000)2000+3000+4000 and I'm trying to update the value 9000 to total_employee_salary attribute.How can I do it in mongo shell.Can anyone please help me out regarding this ...

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("571898dbc000041fe0b921eb"),
        "ORGANIZATION" : "abc",
        "TOTAL_EMPLOYEES" : 10,
        "TOTAL_EMPLOYEES_SALARY" : 0,

        "employees" : [
                {
                        "EMP_NAME" : "vijay",
                        "EMP_SALARY" : 2000,

                },
                {
                        "EMP_NAME" : "vishnu",
                        "EMP_SALARY" : 3000,

                },
                {
                        "EMP_NAME" : "vishal",
                        "EMP_SALARY" : 4000,

                }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing this in bulk for your collection, then the best way to do this is iterate with [`.bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) to write back:

```js
var ops = [];
db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    ops.push({
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
            "update": {
                "$set": {
                    "TOTAL_EMPLOYEE_SALARY": Array.sum(doc.employees.map(function(emp) {
                        return emp.EMP_SALARY
                    }))
                }
            }
        }
    });

    if ( ops.length == 1000 ) {
        db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
        ops = [];
    }
})

if ( ops.length > 0 ) {
    db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
}
```

For "super safe" code though, you probably should be using [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) on iteration of each array element instead:

```js
var ops = [];

db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.employees.forEach(function(emp) {
        ops.push({
            "updateOne": {
                "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
                "update": { 
                    "$inc": { 
                        "TOTAL_EMPLOYEE_SALARY": emp.EMP_SALARY
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        if ( ops.length == 1000 ) {
            db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
            ops = [];
        }
    })
});

if ( ops.length > 0 ) {
    db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
}
```

In earlier shell releases you do it using the ["bulk"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) operations builder directly:

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$set": { 
            "TOTAL_EMPLOYEE_SALARY": Array.sum(doc.employees.map(function(emp) {
                return emp.EMP_SALARY
            }))
        }
    });
    count++;

    if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
})

if ( count % 1000 != 0 ) {
    bulk.execute();
}
```

But what you really should be doing in all instances is updating the `mongodb-shell` package on your system, regardless of the server version used. A modern shell should really be updated just as with a modern API version with your programming language of choice.

You need to iterate documents anyway in order to update each one, so you might as well just sum the content from the array by reading each document.

Just for trivia sake, in modern MongoDB releases the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operator works both as an accumulator as well as now adding items in an array. So now you can do this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "TOTAL_EMPLOYEE_SALARY": {
           "$sum": "$employees.EMP_SALARY"
        }
    }}
])
```

And that will give the total of the array in each document.

In earlier versions than MongoDB 3.2 though, you need to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array and [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) instead:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$employees" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "TOTAL_EMPLOYEE_SALARY": { "$sum": "$employees.EMP_SALARY" }
    }} 
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null, 
            "sum": {
                $sum: "$employees.EMP_SALARY"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: I'm getting result as, { "_id" : null, "sum" : 0 }

Comment: just add _id as some id instead of null.